# how to arrange printing characters

Tags: c#, java, c++, printing

I have absolutely no idea how to do or even to seach for what I want. So I will describe it.
Is it possible to make a program (preffering java, c# or c++) that will take as input strings and creates a "document" that will print the inputs in specific possotion for a A4 paper.

I am thinking if there is something like:

```
String name;
String surname;
String address;
String random;

name.PossisionInPaper(x,y); //print it 3cm from left and 5cm from the top
surname.PossisionInPaper(x1,y1); //same
address.PossisionInPaper(x2,y2); //same
random.PossisionInPaper(x3,y3); //same

document.print(A4);
```

thanks and sorry for the unclear answer.

Comment: yes it's definitely possible to do that.

Comment: Are you wanting to make an excel word, or just like a text file?

Comment: To do this, I would use Apache FOP (which allows you to create PDFs with those type of constraints (Java library).

Comment: as a pdf or doc will be great. Can you give me some more info to search or maybe something to start with?

Comment: Pick a language first.

Comment: You could also do this with postscript. Or most office suites have a feature to print a template using a database, for example: http://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOo3_User_Guides/Writer_Guide/Print_labels_from_db

Answer (score 0):

You can use PrintDocument C#

Here has the class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx

Or make a Database and use CrystalReport for create a document